# REGEX : Customise Journal Entry Numbering

Tags: python, regex

This is a regex that can include all the following capture groups: prefix1, year, prefix2, month, prefix3, seq, suffix.

The prefix* groups are the separators between the year, month and the actual increasing sequence number (seq).

e.g:

- Starting Sequence : INV2301001
- Refund Starting Sequence : RINV2301001
- Sequence Override Regex : (?P<prefix1>[A-Z]{1,})(?P<year>\d{2})(?P\d{2})(?P<seq>\d{3,})

This expressions defines the following invoice numbering scheme : INVYYMMSSS whereby SSS will restart at 001 on a monthly basis.

This will result in the following invoice number for e.g. the third invoice of Februari 2023 : INV2302003

Now, I 'd like to modify my REGEX with this rule :

The expression defines the following invoice numbering scheme : INVYYYYSSS whereby SSS will restart at 001 the 1 april of the next year AND from the 1 january 2024 including 31 march 2024 the YYYY needs to be YYYY-1.

- Start Sequence : 1 april 2023
- End Sequence : 31 march 2024

The result is :

- 1 april 2023 - INV2023001 - YYYY = 2023 and SSS = 001
- 20 december 2023 - INV2023158 - YYYY = 2023 and SSS = 158
- 5 january 2024 - INV2023159 - YYYY = 2023 and SSS = 159
- 31 march 2024 - INV2023230 - YYYY = 2023 and SSS = 230
- 1 april 2024 - INV2024001 - YYYY = 2024 and SSS = 001
- ...

?? Sequence Override Regex : ?

Best Regards,
Youssef

Comment: You should specify the language you are using with your regular expression. I for one have no idea what your usage of `(?P` without being followed by `<group-name>` is supposed to mean.

Comment: - Sequence Override Regex : (?P<prefix1>[A-Z]{1,})(?P<year>\d{2})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<seq>\d{3,})

Comment: The language is python, the link of the code : https://github.com/Noviat/noviat-apps/blob/15.0/account_journal_entry_numbering_scheme/models/account_journal.py

Comment: You needed to escape `<` with a backslash; `<prefix1>` was being interpreted as an HTML tag.